# Can I have multiple sessions with separate jwt tokens stored in secure httponly cookies?

Tags: jwt, local-storage, httpclient, bearer-token, session-storage

If I store a JWT token in a httponly cookie to prevent XSS attacks, but a user has 2 separate accounts for the same site (one that is an admin and the other has reduced readonly permissions for example), is it possible to use httponly cookies for this scenario or is the only way to handle this to store the token in browser session storage ?

Testing has shown the 2nd login to overwrite the cookie generated on the first login